# Laurent series expansion for $\frac{(z-2)}{(z+1)}$centered at z=-1

Tags: complex-analysis

a) How do I find the Laurent series expansion for $\frac{(z-2)}{(z+1)}$centered at z=-1 ?

b) How do I find the region for which it converges?

I've tried rewriting it in different ways, but nothing seems to get me anywhere. I don't think I'm supposed to be integrating anything. Any help would be appreciated, but I ask that you keep the explanation on a low enough level that I can understand, and I don't understand much at the moment.

Edit: I saw the question somewhere else, but I didn't find the answer to be very helpful.

Comment: rewrite the function such that you get terms of $z+1$ everywhere, or a constant. Then, use Maclaurin's expansion at $z+1 = 0$, which will be valid for $| \frac 1 {z+1}| <1$

Comment: Why isn't it just $1-(3/(z+1))$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, yeah in this case its just what you said. I commented procedure for a generic case though.

Comment: How do I do that? Right now I've got it written as 1-3/(z+1). What do I do with that?

Comment: Actually, I think I've got it... I'm just exceptionally lost on how to find the domain of convergence of this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
\begin{align*}
f(z)&=\frac{z-2}{z+1}\\
\end{align*}
is to expand around the center $z=-1$.

> Since there is a simple pole at $z=-1$ we get as region $D$ of convergence
>   \begin{align*}
> D:&\quad 0<|z+1|\\
>  \end{align*}
>
> The  region $D$ is a punctured disc with center $z=-1$ and radius $\infty$. It admits a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=-1$.
>
> *Expansion in $D$:*
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{z-2}{z+1}\\
> &=\color{blue}{-\frac{3}{z+1}+1}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer... quick question, though, do I need to do anything to f(z) and put it in the form a summation, or can I leave it like that?

Comment: @CluelessIndividual:  You're welcome! The form is perfectly  valid. Recall a  Laurent expansion expanded at $z=-1$ has the form $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_j(z+1)^j$. Here $a_{-1}=-3,a_0=1$ and all other $a_j=0$.